# Random selection in pig after doing group BY

Tags: apache-pig

I have a query. I have a data in the format id:int, name:chararray

```
1, abc
1, def
2, ghi,
2, mno
2, pqr
```

After that I do Group BY id and my data becomes

```
1, {(1,abc), (1,def)}
2, {(2,ghi), (2,mno), (2,pqr)}
```

Now I wan to pick a random value from the bag and I want the output like

```
1, abc
2, mno
```

In case we picked up like first tuple for 1 or second tuple for 2

Any idea what How this can be done ?

The question is I have grouped data B;

```
DESCRIBE B
B: {group: int,A: {(id: int,min: chararray,fan: chararray,max: chararray)}}

C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($1)
DESCRIBE C;
C: {A::id: int,A::min: chararray,A::fan: chararray,A::max: chararray}

rand =
    FOREACH B {
        shuf_ = FOREACH C GENERATE RANDOM() AS r, *;  line L
        shuf = ORDER shuf_ BY r;
        pick1 = LIMIT shuf 1;
    GENERATE
        group,
        FLATTEN(pick1);
    };
```

I get an error at line L an error at this point "Pig script failed to parse: expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)"

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested foreach. Assign each item in the bag a random value, order by that value, and choose the first one to keep. You can make it more compact than this, but this shows you each idea.

Script:

```
data = LOAD 'tmp/data.txt' AS (f1:int, f2:chararray);
grpd = GROUP data BY f1;
rand =
    FOREACH grpd {
        shuf_ = FOREACH data GENERATE f2, RANDOM() AS r;
        shuf = ORDER shuf_ BY r;
        pick1 = LIMIT shuf 1;
    GENERATE
        group,
        FLATTEN(pick1.f2);
    };
DUMP rand;
```

Output:

```
(1,abc)
(2,ghi)
```

Running it again:

```
(1,abc)
(2,pqr)
```

And again:

```
(1,def)
(2,pqr)
```

One more time!

```
(1,abc)
(2,ghi)
```

Whee!

```
(1,def)
(2,mno)
```

Comment: Thanks. @WinnieNicklaus Thanks for the answer. The issue that I am facing is that I dont have the data . I only have grouped data "grpd" with me . Now, if I try to regenerate "data" from "grpd" data by doing           data = FOREACH grpd GENERATE FLATTEN($1), I get a relation of the form {A::f1:int, A::f2:chararray} . So, if I use this data in nested FOREACH like FOREACH data GENERATE f2, RANDOM() AS r, it throws an error at this point  "Pig script failed to parse:
expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)" . Any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: Have modified the question . I start with grouped data and dont have data with me from which grouped data is created .

Comment: Rather than change this question to be a whole new question, if you like my solution here upvote and accept it and then ask your follow-up as a separate question.

Comment: I am unable to somehow accept an answer. I have raised a fresh question here stackoverflow.com/questions/24217882/